# How to add Display Text on Ext.Img in extjs4.1.3?

Tags: extjs

I am trying to add  a display `text` on `Ext.Img`....
But their is no such functionality mentioned in sencha docs.
Anybody have some solution for the same.... ?

```
new Ext.Img({
   src: "images/blue_arrow.png",
   id:'demoImgCmp',
   title:'Demo Display Text',
   text:'Demo Display Text',
   html:'<b>Demo Display Text</b>'
})
```

above code is not working for me....

Comment: where do you want to put this text? just below the picture or on the picture!

Comment: I have a similar problem and I would like the text to be below the image, I am using sench touch 2.3